# Whats the difference btw NSString *var = @"value" and NSString *var =[ [NSString alloc] initWithString:@"value"]

Tags: ios, cocoa

Whats the difference(,adv/disadv) in the two ways of initialing a string variable in ios?

`NSString *var = @"value"` and `NSString *var =[ [NSString alloc] initWithString:@"value"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
NSString *var = @"value";
```

Creates an instance of `NSCFConstantString` which is created by the compiler and stored as part of the program's data.  It doesn't respond to `retain` or `release` and can effectively be ignored for memory management purposes.

However the code:

```
NSString *var =[ [NSString alloc] initWithString:@"value"];
```

Allocates an `NSString` object and initialises it with the content of the constant string `@"value"`.  It must be `release`d when no longer required but cannot be updated (it is immutable), so offers little over the first piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

@"value" returns an autoreleased string, but initWithString: returns a retained string, that needs to be released. If you are using ARC there's no difference, because it will release it for you.

Comment: `@"value"` doesn't "return" anything. It *is* a string and it's not autoreleased, it's permanent. Of course, it is correct that, in manual reference counting, you don't own it and have neither the right nor the responsibility to release it. Finally, @sanjana, there can be no advantage to the second form since it is built on the first form.